# Convert swagger json to mashery io-docs json

Tags: java, rest, documentation, swagger, iodocs

Does anyone know about the existence of a JSON-сonverter from Swagger API Docs to Mashery I/O Docs?

Comment: I don't know of one, but it should be doable, however the reverse--from IODoc -> swagger will probably require some manual work.

Answer (score 0):

Tibco/Mashery is supporting Swagger - IODocs conversion in their new cloud tooling, where you define your APIs in Swagger, then can import it in Mashery to have IODocs.
They've put some tools for it on github as ['api-definition-converter'](https://github.com/mashery/masherytools/blob/master/api_definition_converter/README.md)

Answer (score -1):

how about this project: [api-spec-converter](https://github.com/lucybot/api-spec-converter) in github? It converts most of the popular description types.

[**update:**] Currently, it just supports converting from other formats to swagger 2.0 ..